# How set path to template

Tags: thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf. Templates are in root folder templates.

```
    resources:
    -templates
    --accountTemplates
     ---myTemplate.html
    --adminTemplates
    --commonFragment.html
```

I need to insert a commonFragment into the myTemplate.html located in folder accountTemplates

```
    <html>
    ----
    <section th:insert="??????????::commonFragment"/>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: the problem is that the required template is in the lower layer of the level above

Answer (score 0):

use `th:replace` instead of `th:insert`:

```
<html>
----
<section th:replace="accountTemplates/commonFragment::commonFragment"/>

</html>
```

Comment: Just curious: Why are you recommending using `th:replace` instead of `th:insert`? Both are [valid Thymeleaf attributes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#difference-between-thinsert-and-threplace-and-thinclude).

Comment: the problem is that the required template is in the lower layer of the level above